# iOS4 to iOS5, first view of tabBar app is not responding to touches

Tags: iphone, ios5

I have a tabBar App, with 5 tabs. The application was built in previous version of Xcode for iOS4.3. When I run this app from Xcode 4.3 (after changing the base SDK to 'Latest iOS'), in iPhone4.3 simulator the App runs fine. But when I run this App, in iPhone 5.0 simulator

App loads fine i.e. my first screen from the first View controller is loaded correctly. But no touches are recognised by the screen (on tableView, navigationBar and toolBar)

If I select another 'tab', the touch is recognised and touches in the other views loaded from other tabs work fine. Now if I go back to the first view, it works fine.

The tabBarControllers, navigationControllers and the viewControllers I created in Interface Builder and have following code in

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

[self.window addSubview:self.tabBarController.view];
[self.window addSubview:[self.navigationController view]];
[self.window addSubview:self.toolBar];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
}
```

I am missing something that iOS5 needs, but I just can't figure it out. If anyone else had similar problem, it would be great if you could share it and if you have a solution... that would be fantastic!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found my mistake...

I have bit more code in application:DidFinishLaunchingWithOptions where I am initialising other properties of the App and further down in the code, I have repeated the code

```
[self.window addSubview:self.tabBarController.view];
```

This must be creating another layer on top of my view and causing the view to not respond.

(knew I would find the answer on stack overflow :).... so as soon I post the problem here, I see my mistake)